# Layout view are not fit according to given size

Tags: android

I want to set the imagview and textview size at run time half of the width of total screen width. But Its not working fine. Imageview appear small after set the width half of the total screeen.

Please help me to solve this issue. I tried this since last 1 day but could not recognize the problem.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/light_white" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/light_white" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/noticeHeading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dip"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/noticeContent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/noticeHeading"
        android:layout_below="@id/noticeHeading"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="16dip" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/noticeImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/noticeHeading"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/noticeHeading" />
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Code:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(res, container, false);
noticeHeaderTextView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.noticeHeading);

noticeContentTextView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.noticeContent);

noticeImageView = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.noticeImageView);

DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int width = metrics.widthPixels;


noticeImageView.getLayoutParams().width = width / 2;
noticeHeaderTextView.getLayoutParams().width = width / 2;
noticeContentTextView.getLayoutParams().width = width / 2;
```

Comment: Try calls to `requestLayout()` on the modified views (maybe calling on `rootView` is even enough)

Comment: I tried this but on orientation changes its not fit according to size of screen.

Comment: try to give the image constant width, like 100dp

Comment: When I set the image width 100 dp then its not changing at run time according to the screen width through java code

Comment: @MichaelButscher I set the imageview align top to the headertextview but its not appear at align top to it. please help why its so

Answer (score 0):

Use a linear layout and put your relative layout into it , than put set layout_weight to 0.5 for your relative layout .
Apply match_parent in both textview and imageview as height.
Hope this will work.
If this will work in xml you can do the same dynamically via LayoutPerameter class .

Comment: I set the imageview align top to the headertextview but its not appear at align top to it. please help why its so

Comment: You have to call invalidate on each view after changing their dimension or layout perameter manually .Why you are inflating them , when you can directly attach the reference using findViewById ?

Comment: Its fit well but its not align top to the headertextview which is mentioned in the xml layout. Please help me to achieve this

Comment: Have you checked with setting LayoutPeramter to imageview .Use addRule property in which you should give AlignTop and Textview's id .

Comment: I did this in XML layout. Please check it.